# Spring Cloud with Archaius

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-archaius

I'm having a hard time to understand how to use Netflix Archaius with Spring Boot Config.

I have a a microservice that gets the configuration from a Spring Cloud Config Server but I would like to have the configuration automatically refreshed when it is changed. As I understand this can be achieved with Archaius in the client side by pulling the info from the repository.

I have searched but cannot find a tutorial or example where this is done.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I finally used spring-cloud-bus to propagate the refresh command to all the micro-services.

Comment: Hi Oreste, I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to use spring cloud config server + Archaius? There's zero documentation about it :(

Comment: Hello WornOutSoles, I did not use Config Server + Archaius. Only the config server by it self. As far as I know the only way to update the data on the services is to pull it from the config service. This can be done by adding the `@RefreshScope` annotation to the beans and then either calling the `/refresh` endpoint (on the client side) or calling the `/bus/refresh` if using Spring Cloud Bus. Also you can schedule refresh interval within the client application.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the info. I had read about the `/refresh' endpoint, but nothing about scheduling a refresh. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hi, even though you can do schedule for the properties to be refreshed this is not the recommended way. Have a look here:
[http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_environment_changes](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_environment_changes) and here 
[https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/139](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/139)

Comment: Thanks again!, I'll have a look at the links.